# Show dropdown menu to select content in iframe

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

Please have a look at [this link](http://www.alumnei.nl/lid-worden/index.php)

You will see a dropdown menu that gives you the option to show one of the 7 available video-testimonials in the iframe.

Please note: At present, when you do not make a selection, a standard picture showing walking people on the "learning lane", is visible.

If someone makes no selection, so the dropdown shows "maak hier je keuze", I would like to have the present picture automatically be replaced by one of the 7 video-testimonials in such a way that every day of the week automatically one of the 7 video testimonials is shown in the iframe.

### Update

The code I used so far is below:

```js
function setIframeSource() {
   var theSelect = document.getElementById('location');
   var theIframe = document.getElementById('myIframe');
   var theUrl;
 
   theUrl = theSelect.options[theSelect.selectedIndex].value;
   theIframe.src = theUrl;
}
```

```css
div {     
 font-family: Verdana;
 padding: 0px;
   border: 0px solid #000000;  
}
.txt3 {
 font-weight: normal;
     font-size: 100%;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-family: Verdana; 
}
.txt4 {
 font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 100%;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-family: Verdana; 
    margin-top: 2px;   
   margin-left: 0px;
    color:#000000;
 border: 2px solid #BC401E;
}
```

```html
<form id="form1" method="post">
 <label class="txt3"> De video-testimonial van: <select class="txt4" id="location" onchange="setIframeSource()"> 
  <option value="http://www.alumnei.nl/images/learninglane.jpg">... maak hier je keuze ...</option>
  <option value="https://www.youtube.com/embed/tP4i7CiMHh4">Monique van Neutegem</option> 
  <option value="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Bx5Np1wIXYs">Marjon Heintjes</option> 
  <option value="https://www.youtube.com/embed/J-NChlqVAgY">Els de Groot</option> 
  <option value="https://www.youtube.com/embed/r_UB0rTH7SA">Arthur Alferink</option>
  <option value="https://www.youtube.com/embed/t66K_g-fkFY">Monique Fortuin</option>
  <option value="https://www.youtube.com/embed/8DC-3DiVL4A">Erna Slangen</option>
  <option value="https://www.youtube.com/embed/8Gvu_lgZZAM">Stephanie de Witte</option>
 </select></label>
</form>
<br><br>

<iframe id="myIframe" src="http://www.alumnei.nl/images/learninglane.jpg" frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" width="580" height="400" allowfullscreen scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

Comment: I would say that this question is entirely dependent on the link in the question, but I am not clear if the problem described is still visible on the site, or indeed what section it is referring to. Thus this question lacks a convincing [mcve] and could do with being put on hold.

Answer (score 1):

It should be what your need.

```
    <html>
        <head>
        <style>
            div {                   
            font-family: Verdana;
            padding: 0px;
            border: 0px solid #000000;      
        }
        .txt3 {
            font-weight: normal;
                font-size: 100%;
            font-weight: bold;
            font-family: Verdana;   
        }
        .txt4 {
            font-weight: normal;
                font-size: 100%;
            font-weight: bold;
            font-family: Verdana;   
                margin-top: 2px;        
            margin-left: 0px;
                color:#000000;
            border: 2px solid #BC401E;
        }
        </style>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <script language=javascript>
                var theSelect,theIframe;
                var today = new Date(),

            number_of_day = today.getDay();
                $(document).ready(function() {
                //var today = new Date();
                //var n = today.getDay();
                theSelect = document.getElementById('location');
                theIframe = document.getElementById('myIframe');
                theUrl = theSelect.options[number_of_day].value;
                theIframe.src = theUrl;
            });
            function setIframeSource() 
            {
              var theUrl;

              if ( theSelect.selectedIndex > 0) {
                  theUrl = theSelect.options[theSelect.selectedIndex].value;
              } else {
                  theUrl = theSelect.options[number_of_day].value;
              }
              theIframe.src = theUrl;
            }
            </script>
            <form id="form1" method="post">
          <label class="txt3"> De video-testimonial van:
            <select class="txt4" id="location" onchange="setIframeSource()">
              <option value="http://www.alumnei.nl/images/learninglane.jpg">... maak hier je keuze ...</option>
              <option value="https://www.youtube.com/embed/tP4i7CiMHh4">Monique van Neutegem</option>
              <option value="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Bx5Np1wIXYs">Marjon Heintjes</option>
              <option value="https://www.youtube.com/embed/J-NChlqVAgY">Els de Groot</option>
              <option value="https://www.youtube.com/embed/r_UB0rTH7SA">Arthur Alferink</option>
              <option value="https://www.youtube.com/embed/t66K_g-fkFY">Monique Fortuin</option>
              <option value="https://www.youtube.com/embed/8DC-3DiVL4A">Erna Slangen</option>
              <option value="https://www.youtube.com/embed/8Gvu_lgZZAM">Stephanie de Witte</option>
            </select>
          </label>
        </form>
        <br>
        <br>

        <iframe id="myIframe" src="http://www.alumnei.nl/images/learninglane.jpg" frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" width="580" height="400" allowfullscreen scrolling="no"></iframe>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: I quickly checked your solution. It partially does what it needs to do.
The iframe immediately shows the specific video-testimonial for today, which is OK. 

However, when I select one of the other video-testimonials from the dropdown menu, the already present video-testimonial, remains and is not replaced by the selected video-testimonial. 

Looking forward to any suggestion to solve this.

Comment: hi KNVB,

you did a great job. Now it works perfectly !!! Thanks a lot. I owe you a beer (although I don't drink alcohol myself;-))

Comment: Just give me a tick 8)

Answer (score 0):

I think that's what you're after

```js
var current_date = new Date(),
    number_of_day = current_date.getDay();

window.onload = function() {
    setIframeSource();
}

function setIframeSource() {
    var theSelect = document.getElementById('location');
    var theIframe = document.getElementById('myIframe');
    var theUrl;

    if ( theSelect.selectedIndex > 0) {
        theUrl = theSelect.options[theSelect.selectedIndex].value;
    } else {
        theUrl = theSelect.options[number_of_day].value;
    }
    theIframe.src = theUrl;
}
```

```css
div {     
 font-family: Verdana;
 padding: 0px;
   border: 0px solid #000000;  
}
.txt3 {
 font-weight: normal;
     font-size: 100%;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-family: Verdana; 
}
.txt4 {
 font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 100%;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-family: Verdana; 
    margin-top: 2px;   
   margin-left: 0px;
    color:#000000;
 border: 2px solid #BC401E;
}
```

```html
<form id="form1" method="post">
 <label class="txt3"> De video-testimonial van: <select class="txt4" id="location" onchange="setIframeSource()"> 
  <option value="http://www.alumnei.nl/images/learninglane.jpg">... maak hier je keuze ...</option>
  <option value="https://www.youtube.com/embed/tP4i7CiMHh4">Monique van Neutegem</option> 
  <option value="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Bx5Np1wIXYs">Marjon Heintjes</option> 
  <option value="https://www.youtube.com/embed/J-NChlqVAgY">Els de Groot</option> 
  <option value="https://www.youtube.com/embed/r_UB0rTH7SA">Arthur Alferink</option>
  <option value="https://www.youtube.com/embed/t66K_g-fkFY">Monique Fortuin</option>
  <option value="https://www.youtube.com/embed/8DC-3DiVL4A">Erna Slangen</option>
  <option value="https://www.youtube.com/embed/8Gvu_lgZZAM">Stephanie de Witte</option>
 </select></label>
</form>
<br><br>

<iframe id="myIframe" src="http://www.alumnei.nl/images/learninglane.jpg" frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" width="580" height="400" allowfullscreen scrolling="no"></iframe>
```